# how can I get my code to accept multiple delimiters in my rle coding

Tags: java, string, char

i am unable to print out my rle coding properly when inputting multiple delimiters, single delimiter work,

when i do ^5!^4@, it does ^^^^^^^^^^^^4@, something like that, what i want would be !!!!!@@@@

```
private static int getNumber(String rle, int initial)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (initial < rle.length())
    { 
    if (Character.isDigit(rle.charAt(initial)))
        {
        sum = sum * 10 + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(rle.charAt(initial))); 
        initial++;
        }
        else
        {
            initial++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
   


private static String repetition(String rle, char delimiter)
{
    String newRLE = "";
    int starting = 0;

    while (starting < rle.length())
    {
        char character = rle.charAt(starting);
        if (character == delimiter)
        {
            starting++;
            int sum = getNumber(rle, starting);
            char symbol = rle.charAt(starting + String.valueOf(sum).length());
            int count = 0;
            while (count < sum) 
            {
                newRLE += symbol;
                count++;
            }
            starting += String.valueOf(sum).length() + 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            newRLE += character; 
            starting++;
        }
    }
    return newRLE;
}
```

Comment: The updated value of `int initial` will not stick to that updated in `getNumber`. I suggest that you debug your code.

Comment: you should probably break out of the while loop after successfully getting a number

Answer (score 0):

For run-length encoding, consider the following.

```java
String repetition(String rle, char delimiter) {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    String[] strings = rle.split(Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(delimiter)));
    int length;
    char character;
    for (String value : strings) {
        if (value.isEmpty()) continue;
        length = Integer.parseInt(value.substring(0, value.length() - 1));
        character = value.charAt(value.length() - 1);
        string.append(String.valueOf(character).repeat(length));
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

- Split `rle` into an array of `String`, using `delimiter` as the regular expression pattern.
  Use the `Pattern.quote` to avoid collision with a regular expression character.
- Loop through `strings`, skipping over any empty values.
- Assign the `length` and `character` variables.
- Use `String.repeat` to generate a sequence of `character`.
- Append the value to the `StringBuilder`.

Output for `^5!^4@`.

```
!!!!!@@@@
```

Answer (score -1):

public class Delemeter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String rle = "^5!^4@^8$";
    char delimiter = '^';
    String newRLE = "";
    int starting = 0;

    while (starting < rle.length()) {
        char character = rle.charAt(starting);
        if (character == delimiter) {
            starting++;
            int number = getNumber(rle, starting);
            if(number ==0 ) return;
            starting++;
            char symbol = rle.charAt(starting);
            int count = 0;
            while (count < number) {
                newRLE += symbol;
                count++;
            }
            starting ++;
        } else {
            newRLE += character;
            starting++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newRLE);
}

private static int getNumber(String rle, int initial) {
    if (Character.isDigit(rle.charAt(initial))) {
        return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(rle.charAt(initial)));
    }
    return 0;
}}
```

Comment: i tried the code and it works, but was wondering how return 0 works

Comment: wrote code in main method. insted of that you can write your own method and return some thing based on that handel. main method return type was void because of that just I wrote return statement.